# Smaller/Customized In Call DialPad for Android (Samsung S3)

Tags: android, security, galaxy, keypad

Preface:
I moved to the S3 from an old flip phone with a small keypad with which I could easily type things like a telephone banking passcode or the like, shielding one hand with the other as I typed.

With the S3 smartphone, the dialpad is huge, making it hard to shield one hand with the other, and the required finger movement is too great and too easily observed.

Question:
Is there any way to either:
(A) Shrink the size of the "in call" dialpad used by the S3, through any means, even a screen scaler or spliiter, or
(B) Achieve a similar end using a custom dialer?

If I rotate the phone to landscape mode, I do get a nice sized, smaller dialer initially, but once I enter the call (say, voicemail), it jumps back to portrait mode and the stock dialer.  From the research I've already done on custom dialers, it seems that they don't work once a call starts, so I'm not too hopeful.

Is the only solution to root the phone and hack it very deep? (Obviously, anything can be done with a rooted phone if you know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the phone provides such a setting, not really. Generally you cannot change/influence apps other than your own, and the only proper way to do this would be to right a custom dialer and replace the system one. A slightly easier way might be to replace the dialer keypad images with custom ones with smaller font, etc. and just repackage the app, but that won't change the overall layout.

Much better: don't use telephone banking, use their website, smartphone app, etc. (if available, if not bug them to create one :)

Comment: I assume I should keep the question about for a while in the hope of receiving a few different answers.  Not sure how long.